# Import file dynamically from URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-import

Is there any way to load file content from external source at run time?

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
    const [dynamicComponent, fetchComponent] = React.useState(null);

    const loadComponentDynamically = ()=> {

        const _dynamicComponent = (/*import component from external source <external url>/somecomponent.js*/);

        fetchComponent(_dynamicComponent );
    };

    return (
        <div>
             <button onClick={loadComponentDynamically }>Load component</button>
             {dynamicComponent && dynamicComponent()}
        </div>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is create a function that adds the external lib (component) in the document head like the following:

```
const loadComponent = src => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let s;
    s = document.createElement('script');
    s.src = src;
    s.type = 'text/javascript';
    s.onload = resolve;
    s.onerror = reject;
    document.head.appendChild(s);
  });
};
```

When you do this the lib gets added in the window object so you can set a state variable with the content of the lib.
After that you need to create a Wrapper for your component that contains the external component as a prop. When this prop is missing it could just show that it's loading, else when the external lib has loaded and is ready to use it will render that component instead. Such a container is the following:

```
const Wrapper = props => {
  if (props.component) {
    const ComponentToRender = props.component;
    if (props.setRef) {
        return <ComponentToRender {...props} />;
    } else {
        return <ComponentToRender {...props} />;
    }
  } else {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
};
```

I have struggled with this before and this solution works nicely. It's a bit late reply but I hope it helps you or the next one that is facing the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Code-Splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) that provided by react.

For example:

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const [dynamicComponent, fetchComponent] = React.useState(null);

  const loadComponentDynamically = ()=> {

    const _dynamicComponent = React.lazy(() => import('/somecomponent'));

    fetchComponent(_dynamicComponent );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={loadComponentDynamically }>Load component</button>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <dynamicComponent />
      </Suspense>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `React.lazy` function lets you render a dynamic import as a regular component.

The `fallback` prop accepts any React elements that you want to render while waiting for the component to load. You can place the `Suspense` component anywhere above the lazy component. You can even wrap multiple lazy components with a single `Suspense` component.

Comment: Not working, giving below error
Module not found: Can't resolve <External URL>/index.js'.
 
Note: Want to fetch component from outside current project.

Comment: @PrakashGupta The above answer is for internal import. I will add a section to my answer for import from external sources.

Comment: Thanks, let me know if you find solutions related to external url